# serving http and websockets under gunicorn & django

Tags: python, django, websocket

I do not want to use tornado/node.js/twisted and would like to use the gunicorn WSGI server  with gevent worker :). I want to keep this lightweight and do not want to add more services.

I have a django app whos stack is redis, RQ & gunicorn (workers are gevent). I'd like to use websockets to implement push. I'd like to use the app as is, until when a request comes in for '/websocket' in which case I want to use websockets.

What I want to do is done in flask [in the following way](http://socketubs.net/2012/10/28/Websocket_with_flask_and_gevent/):

```
def my_app(environ, start_response):  
    path = environ["PATH_INFO"]  
    if path == "/":  
        return app(environ, start_response)  
    elif path == "/websocket":  
        handle_websocket(environ["wsgi.websocket"])   
    else:  
        return app(environ, start_response)
```

How do I do this in django? Here is my wsgi.py:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "dapi.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

In order to do something like this, do I have to override the `WSGIHandler()`? I'd be grateful for an example. I'd like to have the base http server (run through `python manage runserver`) to work.

Comment: Check out [gevent-socketio](http://gevent-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)